# How do you translate "Me apetece mucho hacer un cartel y un eslogan, pero... ¿qué serán los chasquis?"

Tags: traducción

I've tried numerous translators for this sentence I found in my Spanish textbook. I have found that a Chasqui is a sort of Incan messenger, but this seems to make no sense in the context of the sentence from what I can tell.

> Me apetece mucho hacer un cartel y un eslogan, pero... ¿qué serán los chasquis?

For context, the next sentence is

> No tengo ni idea, la verdad. Quizá sean autos o algún animal...

The sentences are dialogue. It seems the second sentence is saying the chasquis are cars or animals, which makes no sense. I'll just say the person really no tiene ni idea. Also, this is the only relevant part of the text. The two sentences are from a dialogue used to exemplify "Me apetece . . ." and "No tengo ni idea. . . ." There is no other context.

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide more context since the question as it is does not make any sense.

Comment: Note neither of the two speakers in your text knows what *chasquis* means. The first one is asking what they are (the future tense expresses uncertainty/surprise/curiosity), and the second one says he has no idea.

Comment: Okay, thinking it over maybe the *chasquis* would be the medium through which said sign and slogan would be shown, and the second speaker says maybe a [car](http://www.ideasyahorro.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ganar-dinero-publicidad-coche.jpg) or [animals](http://imagenes.lainformacion.com/2012/11/14/mundo/paseo-burro-burrada_533657552_28858055_626x472.jpg).

Comment: @Yay Thank you for the pictures! This actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: One is asking what a _chasqui_ is and the other says he doesn't know but that he thinks it might be a car or some sort of animal, there's not much more than that.

Comment: Did you see that after you posted the second line you got more answers?. Why don't you just take a picture of the page and add it to your question? With the full context we would be able to help a lot more.

Comment: @DGaleano we are not allowed to bring textbooks home. otherwise I would've

Comment: I'd guess the prior context establishes that the poster has to include a chasqui (probably more than one) and the speaker is enthused but unsure how to proceed since he does not know what a chasqui is. Neither does his/her companion.

Comment: @DavisRash please [edit] your question to provide more details. Otherwise, it is quite unclear and we cannot answer it.